# grant user in another database

Tags: oracle

How can I grant 'select' on sequence to user in another database.

the syntax: grant select on SEQ_NAME to USER_NAME;
allowed only to users in the same database.

Comment: Are you using a DBLINK?  Please can you confirm what you mean by "other database"?

Comment: I don't now DBLINK. "other database" - I mean that the sequence declared by user x@ **DB1** and I what to use it by user y@ **DB2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remote user first needs to have some way to connect to your database. In Oracle this is done by creating a database link. The database link has to be created in the remote database and has to connect to your database.
In the connect definition to your database, a user can be specified to use for the connection in your database. That user needs to have the select privilege.
If there is no user specified in the database link definition, the remote user name will connect to your database using the same name as the remote username, using the same password.
So, in both cases the privilege has to be granted to a user in your database.

```
create database link to_my_database connect to guest_in_my_database identified by 'bigsecret' using tns_alias_to_my_database;
```

In this example, you need to grant to guest_in_my_database, after it has been created and given at least the create session privilege.